# How can I add an "Attach image to this post/page" link on the Add Media lightbox?

Tags: images, attachments

How can I add an "Attach image to this post/page" link on the **Add Media** lightbox?

My theme uses attached images to generate sliders. I want to be able to attach images from **Media Library** to the current post/page (the one I'm editing). How can I hook into the **Add Media** window to add a link?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just enable [post thumbnails](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)?

Comment: What's that? The images are not attached, so I can't use thumbnails.

Comment: You want to attach multiple images to post/page and generate slider with that images?

Comment: Yes, and the images are already in the Media Library. I don't want to INSERT them, I only need to ATTACH them. The theme does the rest.

Comment: By post thumbnail you can select already inserted image, but only one to post/page. I have no idea how this could be changed to work with multiple images

Comment: I know I can do this from Media Library -> Unattached Images -> and then attach them one by one to any post or page, but I want to do it from the Add Media window.